# PgAdmin Object File cannot be empy

Tags: c, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to create a C language function in pgadmin4, but I don't know what to put in object file, and link symbol.

[image]

in object file I have put this path but I don't know what else I should put.

[image]

Comment: You are comfortable implementing a function in C, but not to run a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement manually? Strange. However, rhe rules on where Postgres searches for the object file is documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html I don't use pgAdmin, but it should follow the same rules as this is just an obfuscated way to create the syntax for CREATE FUNCTION

Answer (score 0):

The "object file" is the shared library you built from your C source code and installed in the PostgreSQL library directory, and the "link symbol" is the name of the exported function.

The PostgreSQL documentation has lots of information about writing C functions.